# Play! Framework: How do I lookup an item from a "slugify()" url?

Tags: playframework

The play framework has a function in the view to create an SEO friendly URL via the `slugify()` function.  There does not seem to be an "unslugify" function, so how do you lookup models from the slugified parameter?

If for instance I have a Blog model which has a title property set to "hello world", slugify would produce "hello-world".  If I then perform a query `Blog.find("byTitle", title)` where title is the slugified title, it will return no results.  How can you lookup a model using the provided slug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a method, but I am not surprised. Slugify removes characters from the string and unslugify would not know where to put it back in.

For example, if you look at the URL for this question, it is

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/4433620/play-framework-how-do-i-lookup-an-item-from-a-slugify-url
```

It has removed the exclamation (!), parentheses and the quotes from the title of this question. How would an unslugify method know how and where to put those characters back in?

The approach you want to take is to also include the ID, just as the stackoverflow URL has.

If you wanted to take the same format as the stackoverflow URL, your route would be

```
GET /questions/{id}/{title}              Question.show()
```

Then in your action, you would ignore the title, and simply do `Blog.findById(id);`

You then have a SEO friendly URL, plus use a good REST approach to accessing the Blog post.

Comment: Just to emphasize, the slugified parameter exists *solely* for search engines.  Your site should work the same with or without it.

Comment: This was the way I had already went, thanks for the validation to my approach!

Comment: Is there a way that anyone knows to have the URL automatically include the slugified title, or does that need to be specified when each URL is generated. i.e. @{Blog.show(id, title.slugify)}. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can: you need to store the slugified string into your db.

In your *model*:

```
//import ... ;

import play.templates.JavaExtensions;

@Entity
public class Product extends Model{
    public String name;
    public String slug;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void pre_update(){
        this.slug = JavaExtensions.slugify(this.name);

        // Prevent duplicates
        Long dup_slug = Product.count("bySlug", this.slug);
        if(dup_slug>0){ this.slug += "_"+this.id; }
    }
}
```

In your *controller*:

```
public static void show(String prod_slug) {
    Product prod = Product.find("bySlug", prod_slug).first();
    notFoundIfNull(prod);
    renderText("Product: <a href='/products/"+prod.slug+"'>"+prod.name+"</a>");
}
```

Please remember to define your *routes*:

```
# Products
GET     /products/                              Products.index
GET     /products/{prod_slug}                   Products.show
```